# Why react mui pagination component causes Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('/.js') is not a valid name. error?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using mui for my react project. When i am using button component of mui it is working but pagination component creates this error:

*DOMException: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('/7f3bb9f17db538730cfa2032641aa64e.js') is not a valid name.*

In another project which is created with create-react-app is working but this is not working.

I tried lots of things like reinstall node_modules, searched for any clue about mui in webpack but could not solve the problem.

```
import React from 'react'
import Pagination from '@mui/material/Pagination';
import './index.css'

const Table = () => {


  return (
    <div className='table'>
        <Pagination count={10} variant="outlined" color="primary" />

    </div>
  )
}

export default Table
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using file-loader for svg,img.. in webpack but it should be url-loader

before:

```
    {
        test: /\.png|svg|jpg|gif$/,
        use: ["file-loader"],
    },
```

after:

```
    {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|gif|png|svg)$/i,
        use: [
        {
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: 10000
          }
        }
      ]
    },
```

note: do not forget to install url-loader..